# Comparing option return value to option value

Tags: f#

i'm trying to do something super simple...

```
let Average (a : float list) : (float option) =
    let add (x : float) (y : float) = x+y

    match a.Length with
    | 0 -> None
    | 1 -> None
    | _ -> Some((List.fold add 0.0 a)/(float)a.Length)    

let CompareResult func input expected =
         (func input) = expected
```

That's my two functions. 
When i do 
CompareResult Average [5.8;6.6;9.4;3.5;4.0] (Some 5.86)
I'm getting false.

Any ideas why this could be would be greatly appeciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of floating point arithmetic.  Two seemingly equal values (which both display as 5.86) may not really be equal due to tiny differences.  See, e.g. https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: Okay thanks. I've changed the code to ((func input) - expected) <= System.Double.Epsilon, but now i'm having issues subtracting an option float from an option float. Double.Epsilon apparently seems to return a float?

Comment: Use of `System.Double.Epsilon` is [not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.7.2#Equality) for equality tests.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the discrepancies resulting from the limitations of the internal representation, the issue may also result from loss of precision while calculating the average in floating point arithmetic.

```
5.86.ToString "G17"
// val it : string = "5,8600000000000003"
(Seq.average [5.8;6.6;9.4;3.5;4.0]).ToString "G17"
// val it : string = "5,8599999999999994"
```

Consider using a more appropriate numeric data type:

```
Seq.average [5.8;6.6;9.4;3.5;4.0] = 5.86
// false
Seq.average [5.8M;6.6M;9.4M;3.5M;4.0M] = 5.86M
// true
```

---

To answer the actual question, how to equality test `Option<float>` values: by "lifting" the floats out of the options and then perform the equality test on them. Lift is a common operation on [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) in functional programming.

Starkly simplified, we are going to run the bespoke test only when both arguments are `Some`-cases. This is easily done by pattern matching on the discriminated union cases.

```
let eps = 1e-7  // or whatever is sensible in your domain
let equalityCompareFloatOption x y =
    match x, y with
    | Some x', Some y' -> abs(x' - y') < eps
    | _ -> x = y
// val equalityCompareFloatOption : x:float option -> y:float option -> bool

equalityCompareFloatOption
     (Seq.average[5.8;6.6;9.4;3.5;4.0] |> Some) (Some 5.86)
// val it : bool = true
```